# VSE - Audio wave forms are tiny, audio channel is huge

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'd like to see more detail of my audio wave form:
[image: wave forms for ants]

As you can see I've zoomed the channels appropriately. All the places that have "no" wave form actually have audio. When I play the animation, it renders the audio fine. Increasing the Volume, Pitch or Pan has no effect.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the volume should work:

[image]

If you need to have different volumes at different times, then change an area to graph editor, click the small circle next to the volume widget, so you can work on a curve controlling the volume in Graph editor.